# Escape Curly Brackets in props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a Handlebars template to be processed as `this.props.children` using the following JSX snippet:

```
<MyComponent>
  My address is {{address}}.
</MyComponent>
```

The result is `Uncaught ReferenceError: address is not defined`.

A workaround was to use something like:

```
<MyComponent>
  <span content="My address is {{address}}."></span>
</MyComponent>
```

And then use `this.props.children.props.content`. This is the only way I've found to essentially escape `{{address}}` being interpreted as interpolation by JSX.

Is there a straightforward way to escape curly braces in JSX?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to wrap component content into curly braces:

```
<MyComponent>
  {"My address is {{address}}."}
</MyComponent>
```

All content in braces will be an expression and will not be parsed as JSX. At least, it works in [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3CMyComponent%3E%0A%20%20%7B%22My%20address%20is%20%7B%7Baddress%7D%7D.%22%7D%0A%3C%2FMyComponent%3E&utm_content=buffer49995&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Answer (score 4):

As [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are introduced in ES6, we can use them here without introducing too many curly braces.

```
render() {
     let address = 'Somewhere on this earth!';
     return (
        <MyComponent>
            {`My address is ${address}`}
        </MyComponent>    
     );
}
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cysn4dpw/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, OP wanted to escape curly braces. You have shown how to use them in template literals.

Comment: Thank you @S.. for your comment. I've suggested a better way that doesn't hurt the readability and maintainability of code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<MyComponent>
  {'My address is {{address}}.'}
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not allowed to comment yet ... ;)
Of course you don't have to escape the whole text - just the curly brackets. What you do in your case is a matter of personal preference.

```
<MyComponent>
 My address is {"{{"}address{"}}"}.
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the new JavaScript string literals.

THIS:

```
{`{}`}
```

SHOULD PRINT:

```
{}
```

So, in your case make all of it a string

```
{`My address is {{address}}.`}
```

Should print:

```
My address is {{address}}.
```

Peace! ✌️